# creating a configuration file for pubsub event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a **GCP** cloud build configuration yaml file that automatically creates topic and subscription for PubSub.The steps should be included in the yaml file itself .I am confused and tried this :(I am bit confused is it right or not.Also where to start or look for such references .)

````
steps:
 -name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker’
  args: [‘build’, ‘-t’ ,’gcr.io/$project_id/pubsub_name',’.’]
 -name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker’
  args: [‘beta’,’run’,’deploy’,’pubsub-name’,’—image’,’gcr.io/$project_id/',’--region','us-vental1'] ```
````

Comment: You have to use the GCLOUD cli in your 2nd step

Comment: typo , yes it was gcloud instead of docker  .But then on triggering it does not work . Also how do I create a topic or subscription for pubsub using this .

Comment: If you use gcloud to deploy Cloud Run, you can use gcloud in different steps to create topic and subscription.